# How to configure TeXLive search paths?

Tags: installing, texlive, paths

Every time I run `pdflatex` my whole home directory is scanned. It takes forever and one cpu core is at 100% usage.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 TeXLive packages and can't find where this is set.

`kpsepath tex | tr ':' '\n'` does not list my home directory directly only `~/texmf` and `~/.texmf`.

Please help.

Comment: It would be helpfull to add the version number of your `tex` distribution (actuall is 2012) and how you installed the distribution. How do you know that your complete home directory is scanned (I have no Ubuntu)?

Comment: For completeness texlive-binaries is `2009-11ubuntu2`. And I can tell that the whole directory is scanned by using `strace`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You very likely have your $HOME containing a final slash /. This expands to // after $HOME in the definition of $TEXMF and thus all of your home is searched.

By default $HOME does *not* contain this final /, so it might have been added locally in your init files.

Other than that, on Debian/Ubuntu TeX Live you change settings by adding lines to `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` (creating if necessary).

Comment: I had to remove the final `/` in `/etc/passwd` as that is the source for `$HOME`. Very annoying...

Comment: @tauran `/etc/passwd` should never have trailing slashes on directory names anyway so a bonus side effect of this problem is that you got your system cleaned up.